# Maps in Go - how to avoid double key lookup?

Tags: go

Suppose I want to update some existing value in a map, or do something else if the key is not found. How do I do this, without performing 2 lookups? What's the golang equivalent of the following C++ code:

```
auto it = m.find(key);
if (it != m.end()) {
    // update the value, without performing a second lookup
    it->second = calc_new_value(it->second);
} else {
    // do something else
    m.insert(make_pair(key, 42));
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go does not expose the map's internal (key,value) pair data structure like C++ does, so you can't replicate this exactly.

One possible work around would be to make the values of your map pointers, so you can keep the same values in the map but update what they point to.  For example, if `m` is a `map[int]*int`, you could change a value with:

```
v := m[10]
*v = 42
```

With that said, I wouldn't be surprised if the savings from reducing the number of hash lookups will be eaten by the additional memory management overhead.  So it would be worth benchmarking whatever solution you settle on.

Comment: Any reason for the down vote?  I can update the answer if you think there is something wrong.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot. The situation is actually the same with Python dicts. However it shouldn't matter. Both lookup and assignment to a Go map are amortized O(1). Combining the two operations has the same time complexity.

Comment: In one of my benchmarks I get this  (map access dominates the CPU cycles) :
```1.58s 28.11% 28.11%      1.66s 29.54%  runtime.mapaccess2_fast64
 0.87s 15.48% 43.59%      0.92s 16.37%  runtime.mapaccess1_fast64```

Comment: > lookup and assignment to a Go map are amortized O(1)
Sorry, this is a pet peeve of mine; it's a common and serious misunderstanding of the performance of hash maps. Lookup is constant with respect to the *size of the map*. It is `O(n)` with respect to the *size of the key* (generally hash functions are linear in the number of bits in the key). So for, say, string keys, the hashing can easily dominate and turn lookups into linear operations, and O(2n) vs. O(n) can make an important difference.

Comment: @decitrig that's very interesting. But if the keys are all of the same length, or the length themselves are O(1), we don't care? Also if we treat the length of the key as k, it's O(k) and we know k is small. Also many languages cache the hash too, Python for example again.

Comment: Sure, if we're allowed to make arbitrary assumptions about key size or implementation we can make it as efficient as we want. But the question doesn't stipulate anything about key size and it's not about Python. The reason c++ has the API the author quoted  is precisely to avoid computing expensive hashes multiple times, because it (like Go) has no way to cache hash results for arbitrary types.

This is analogous to quicksort: qsort is not nlgn, it's nlgn *in the average case*.

The reason i get picky about this is because hash flooding attacks are a real thing.